# How would I capture all keystrokes from a windows service?

Tags: .net

I saw some software the other day that logs all keystrokes that are typed on the machine that it is installed on.  How would I go about writing something like this using a .NET Windows service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990(VS.85).aspx)

Note: You don't need admin rights for this and I haven't found a single virus scanner or malware tool complain about code which uses this. AFAIK, there isn't even an API to enumerate all installed hooks, so anyone can install a keyboard logger on Windows systems and there is no way to notice.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalsystemhook.aspx